# Given a positive integer $t$ does there always exist a natural number $k$ such that $(k!)^2$ is a factor of $(2k-t)!$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For all natural numbers $k$ the ratio
$$
\frac{(2k)!}{(k!)^2}=\binom{2k}k
$$
is an integer. From staring at the Pascal triangle long and hard, we know that these ratios grow rather quickly as $k$ increases. It is therefore natural to think that may be some factors from the numerator can be dropped in such a way that the ratio would still be an integer. More specifically, can we, for some carefully chosen $k$, leave out a chosen number of largest factors. In other words, given an integer $t>0$ does there exist a natural number $k$ such that
$$\frac{(2k-t)!}{(k!)^2}\in\Bbb{Z}?$$

---

My curiosity about this comes from [a question we had in May](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3689503/11619). The asker there had found the smallest $k$ that works for each of $t=1,2,\ldots,8$. In that question it was settled that with $t=9$ the smallest $k$ that works is $k=252970$.

---

It is natural to think about such divisibility questions one prime factor $p$ at a time. It is well known that if we write a natural number $m$ in base $p$,
$$m=\sum_{i=0}^\ell m_ip^i$$
with the digits $m_i\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$, then the highest power of $p$ that divides $m!$ is equal to
$$
\nu_p(m!)=\frac1{p-1}\left(m-\sigma_p(m)\right),
$$
where
$$\sigma_p(m)=\sum_{i=0}^\ell m_i$$
is the sum of "digits" of $m$ in base $p$. Written in this way, my question asks for a given $t$, whether there exists a $k$ such that the inequality
$$
(2k-t)-\sigma_p(2k-t)\ge 2k-2\sigma_p(k)
$$
holds for all primes $p\le k$.

---

As we have that slack one might expect this to be possible. But I'm not sure. One obstruction comes from primes just below $k$. If $k-(t/2)<p<k$, then $p^2$ is a factor in the denominator, but $2p$ is too large to appear as factor in the numerator, so $p^2\nmid (2k-t)!$. Occasionally a small prime is also problematic. It is not clear to me how to approach this. A construction may exist. The only thing this reminds me of is the elementary exercise $(k!)^{k+1}\mid (k^2)!$, but that doesn't seem to apply here.

---

In a [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3689759/11619) under the answer to the linked question user [metamorphy](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/543769/metamorphy) reports having confirmed this up to $t\le14$.

---

Edit/Note: The available evidence (see also Sil's comment under this question) suggests that, at least when looking for the smallest $k$ that works for a given $t$, whenever a chosen $k$ works for an odd number $t$, that same $k$ also works for $t+1$. If the main question proves to be too difficult to crack, steps towards explaining this phenomenon are also interesting.

Comment: In your second to last paragraph, "primes just below $k$" can be accounted for by simply choosing a large prime gap and setting $k$ at the end of it...

Comment: If somebody knows a more common symbol for the digit sum function, please ping me, and I will edit (or edit yourself). Here $B$ stands for *base*, but that is not the greatest of justifications :-)

Comment: Wikipedia has a dedicated [page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digit_sum), but still [inconsistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Number_theory). I met $\sigma_p(n)$ in several places.

Comment: Thanks, @metamorphy. Let's go with $\sigma_p(n)$, *Sigma for Sum* :-/

Comment: Why is this not a duplicate of the [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3689503/smallest-number-k-in-mathbbn-such-that-2k-9-equiv-0-pmodk2) you link to?

Comment: @RossMillikan The other question doesn't show the existence of a valid $k$ for all $t$, only a faster way of computing the minimal valid $k$.

Comment: This question was created to get more material for [the Pearl Dive](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102837/pearl-dive).

Comment: Interesting question. Why not post to MO instead?

Comment: @user21820 I don't think of this as a research question.  More like a curiosity. If a connection with a research problem is unveiled, so much better.

Comment: I see okay. I suppose that's a fine distinction, though I've seen numerous curiosity posts on MO, and there are many number theory experts there that probably won't see your question here. Then again, I suppose you have more rep here to offer more bounties. =D

Comment: @user21820 That last point has admittedly a lot of weight. Drawing a bit of attention to the Pearl Dive while using the site :-)

Comment: Heheh then I'll upvote your comment linking that, since you can't upvote yourself.

Comment: @user21820 If you know of an acceptable way to advertise in MO, I'm all ears. The ones I know of feel a bit too intrusive/self-serving. If the Pearl Dive lifts off the ground, then that might warrant a note in MO:

Comment: Actually I don't know, but I noticed that due to the much lower rate of questions on MO, each question actually gets far more attention than on Math SE (which is full of PSQs and routine homework). Even bounties on Math SE don't seem to work well.

Comment: The title should be edited, because a natural number is the same as a positive integer- whereas the title makes it sound as if it is not.

Comment: @RadialArmSaw To me (and many others) $0$ is a natural number. And it doesn't really make a difference to the question - $t=0$ is the uninteresting case anyway.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Catalan numbers are $\frac{1}{n+1} \binom{2n}{n}$, which has a very similar flavor. Proving that even they are integers takes at least a little effort. Writing them as a difference of binomial coefficients is simplest, but generalizing that here seems hopeless. The other main argument is the "cycle lemma", which describes the Catalan numbers as counting equivalence classes of n-element subsets of [2n]. That too seems unlikely to help here. Your problem feels much more number-theoretic/real analytic to me.

Comment: @JoshuaP.Swanson I also had association with Catalan numbers. However the main difference is that **each** Catalan number is integer, but here we need to show that there **exists** $k$ such that $\binom{2k}{k}$ is divisible by $(2k)\cdot(2k - 1)\cdots(2k - t + 1)$

Comment: As for the further verification, $k=159329615$ works for $t \leq 16$ and $k=2935782898$ works for $t \leq 18$. Next $k$ must be greater than $15980000001$ per my calculations. Though this does not help much in revealing generic pattern, except that all these $k$ have very few and distinct prime divisors (i guess there is some probabilistic reason for that).

Comment: Thanks @Sil. If you can build a heuristic argument around that observation, it would be better than whatever we have up to this point! Observe that this time we don't need to find the smalles $k$.

Comment: @Sil Can you explain why only even values of $t$ seem to be interesting? IIRC in all the instances the smallest $k$ that worked for $2\ell-1$ also worked for $2\ell$.

Comment: The previous comment may also be seen as stating that possibly the odd values of $t$ are the hard ones to satisfy, and the next even number comes free of charge.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I was wondering the same, but I don't see any obvious reason why it should be so. Another way to look at this observation is the other way around: let $k$ be fixed and $t_{k}$ be maximal $t$ such that $\frac{(2k-t)!}{(k!)^2}$ is an integer, then data actually shows that $t_{k}$ is even very often, but no always! First few counter examples to this are $k=4731,t_k=3$, $k=6111, t_k=3$. This has interesting sub-observation, in all counter examples I found, $t_k \mid k$.

Comment: Let $(2k-t)!=A(k!)^2C_1$ and $(2k-t-1)!=B(k!)^2C_2$ where the smallest prime factor of $A,B$ is not contained in $k!$, and $C_1=\prod\limits_{i\le k}i^{\alpha_i}$ and $C_2=\prod\limits_{i\le k}i^{\beta_i}$. Then $(2k-t)BC_2=AC_1\implies 2k-t=\frac AB\prod\limits_{3\le p\le k}p^{\alpha_i-\beta_i}$ (evidently $B\mid A$). This shows that the phenomenon can only hold (if at all) for odd $t$, since otherwise the LHS is even, contradicting the non-existence of powers of $2$ on the RHS.

Comment: The only primes that can cause trouble are primes dividing $k, \dots, k +1 - \lfloor t/2 \rfloor$. If we assume that the sizes of the prime factors of these numbers are roughly independent and follow the known distribution, and that for each such prime $p$ the $p$-adic digits of $k$ (except the last one) are independent, then I think we get a positive proportion of numbers $k$ satisfying this property (but this proportion goes to $0$ at least exponentially in $t$.)

Comment: A necessary condition is that all $p$ dividing $k, \dots ,k+1 - \lfloor t/2 \rfloor$ have size at most $\sqrt{2k-t}$. I would guess modern number theory cannot even guarantee the existence of numbers satisfying this weaker condition, but I'm not sure.

Comment: @Sil Hey, I was wondering if you could provide the code you wrote to confirm that "k  must be greater than 15980000001 per my calculations". I also wrote some code that would calculate that, but it definitely breaks after 3 billion, so I am really curios to see how you confirmed anything for 16 billion.

P.S. I am the author of the question this question was referencing in the second paragraph :)

Comment: @Lainad I have only vague memory of the problem, but I happen to found 3750945.mw which has some Maple code in it (see https://pastebin.com/aPBm4P3i ). Since it is a CAS system, it has arbitrary precision so big numbers are not problem (as long as you have enough memory), plus for $v_p(k!)$ I use Legendre's formula to avoid unnecessarily large numbers. Other than that, it is just waiting (i would expect this took several days for the values mentioned above, but basically you just define $t$ and then it finds smallest $k$ that works, plus some stoping/continuing from latest known $k$)

Answer (score 1):

Note:  this is not a complete solution, rather it is an approach that may provide insight or be workable into a solution.

Using the terms in the question, let $t\ge 1$ be given and consider $\frac{(2k-t)!}{(k!)^2}$.  If we take $q=(t+1)\#+1+t$ then each of the numbers $q-t+1,q-t+2,\dots, q$ has a factor in common with $q-t-1$.  If $2k\equiv q+\{0,1\}\mod (t+1)\#$ and $2k\ge q$ then there will be no primes $p\in [2k-t+1, 2k]$ and therefore if $p\mid k!$ then $p^2\mid (2k-t)!$.  (Note that odd $q$ means $2k\equiv q+1\mod (t+1)\#$ and $(q+1, (t+1)\#)\gt 2$.)  Moving forward, assume that $2k\equiv_{(t+1)\#}t+1+(t\mod 2)$.

Next consider a factor $p^r\mid k!$ such that $p^{2r}\nmid (2k-t)!$, which means that $p^u\mid x,x\in[2k-t+1,2k]$.  Begin with $u=2$.  If $p^2\ge t$ then we must move $p^2$ into the given arrangement also, which can be accomplished by $p^2\equiv 2k-q-[1,t]\mod (t+1)\#$.  This same process can be applied for each $p^u > t$.  More specifically, let $u_p=\lfloor\log_p t\rfloor +1$, then $p^{u_p} > t$ for each given $p$ and the specified modulus would be along the lines
$$q=t+1+\prod_{p\le t}p^{\lfloor\log_p t\rfloor+1}$$
with $2k\ge q+\{0,1\}$.  This value can probably be simplified as $2k\ge t!+t+\{1,2\}$.

In order to use this further it might be provable that each prime increases its total factor count of $\binom{2n}n$ as $n$ increases, or as $n$ increases in some patterned manner, so that a bound can be determined.  Specifically, it is clear in the patterns that for $p=2$ the quantity $\binom{2^n-2}{2^{n-1}-1}$ has $n-1$ factors of $2$, while for $p>2$ the quantity $\binom{p^n+1}{\frac{p^n+1}2}$ has $n-1$ factors of $p$.  There are specific repeating patterns of each prime up to each of these particular boundaries, but I have not been able to tame them as yet.  However, the patterns appear to present a form of "modular arithmetic" which seems to have potential for leveraging into a value for $2k$ for a given value of $t$, e.g., every $3$rd $n$ in $\binom{2n}n$ or every $5$th, etc.