# Generalization of "Choose" function

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integers

**Observation:** It's well known that $\frac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}=$$2n\choose{n}$ is an integer.
**Problem:** Is the above true even if we decrease the numerator's factorial? I.e for some constant $k$, is there always an integer $n$ such that $\frac{(2n-k)!}{(n!)^2}$ is an integer ?
**For example:** let $k=3$. Then, one can validate that for $n=210$ the expression $\frac{(2n-k)!}{(n!)^2}$ is an integer!
**note:** I am looking for only $1$ such $n$ for every integer $k$.

Comment: Not sure if this helps. You need for every prime $p$ that:

$$\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor \frac{2n-k}{p^j}\right\rfloor\geq 2\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left\lfloor\frac{n}{p^j}\right\rfloor$$

In particular, $n,n-1,\dots,n-\lfloor k/2\rfloor$ cannot be primes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Given a positive integer $t$ does there always exist a natural number $k$ such that $(k!)^2$ is a factor of $(2k-t)!$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3750945/given-a-positive-integer-t-does-there-always-exist-a-natural-number-k-such-t) - found as the top result in an [Approach0 search](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cfrac%7B(2n-k)!%7D%7B(n!)%5E2%7D%24%2C%20OR%20content%3Ainteger&p=1).

Comment: You can also rephrase this as asking when $\binom{m}{n}$ is divisible by $(m-n+1)(m-n+2)\cdots n,$ for $2n\geq m\geq n.$